# Custom UIView in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, uiview, interface-builder

I am trying to create a custom UIView for an iPhone app. The UIView contains some standards views such as UILabel and UIImageView.

I have created a new nib file and designed the control there. Afterwards I created a new class that extends UIView. I have put owner to the class, linked the controls from the nib to the class, implemented the methods in initWithCoder: etc.

Here is the catch: if in the storyboard I add a UIView object with the my UIView custom class, at build time everything works. But in the Interface Builder I still see a white rectangle.
I had a look on the Apple tutorial here (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html) and it works as stated if I implement drawRect method.
But the controls are not displayed, such as UILabel.

My question is if there is any way to see the custom control in the Interface Builder and how may I achieve this?

Comment: It seems it can't be done, at least not yet. I found here (http://www.maytro.com/2014/04/27/building-reusable-views-with-interface-builder-and-auto-layout.html) a tutorial and a mention that is not rendered in IB.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I am quite sure that it's feasible :) If you still want my answer I will post it here